# Add change() function to all but last element of a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jquery's change() to perform actions when SELECTs of a certain class are changed, however I do not want the last drop down in the DOM of this class to perform the action.

I have tried

```
$("select.prodOption").change(function(){
        if($(this) !== $("select.prodOption").filter(':last')){
            //do stuff
        }
 });
```

hoping that the called function would first check if this is the last element and only do the action if false.

I also tried adding a blank function seperately to the last element too, hoping this would overide the previous call, but both run instead.

```
$("select.prodOption").filter(':last').change(function(){ /*do nothing*/ });
```

Anybody got any ideas how I assing an onchange call to all but the last element of a class.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question right:

```
$("select.prodOption").not(':last').change(function(){          
        // do stuff
});
```

should do it

Comment: Was the first check not enough? ;)

Comment: thats what you got if you just copy'n'paste

Comment: wahahahahhahaha lol!.... and you got the accepted answer... :D *thats what you got if you just copy'n'paste*

Answer (score 1):

lol on `/*do nothing*/`, try

```
$("select.prodOption:not(:last)").change(function(){...});
```

Comment: you accepted the zero? hehe oh well.. ;) I'm always glad to help.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to negate the [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) like this:

```
$("select.prodOption:not(:last)").change(function(){
  //do stuff
});
```